# Placing covered vias routing signals under microcontroller termal pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, via

Placing covered vias routing signals under microcontroller termal pads is a good practic? I mean to reduce soldered termal pad area to center(connected with vias to gnd) and place covered(with soldermaks) signal vias in the inner corner of IC package.

Comment: The technical term is "tented".

Comment: Is it entirely without risk? No. Can it work well enough? Yes. Should you expect problems? Ask your fab! If they use cheap thin, runny solder mask you may, in some possibly cases, get "naked edges" near the hole on your tented vias. Which would be of the not-good type of thing to happen. You can then prevent that with much tinier holes in your vias. Though I have not had problems with tented vias yet, it is theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against this, for at least two reasons:

1. The thickness of soldermask varies, but it averages about 0.5 mil (0.0127mm).  This doesn't seem like much, but it will cause a gap underneath your thermal pad.  You may need to open up your solder stencil aperture to make sure there is enough solder to make a solid connection.
2. Tented vias often are not fully encased in soldermask.  I have a recent PCB where the soldermask "ran away" from the highest ridges of the tented vias.   These conductive gaps would obviously cause problems under a thermal pad (or any other conductive material).